# Get the name of a picture in Word from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Using Excel VBA, I need to get the name of a picture in the Active Word document.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim DocumentoDestino As Object
Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.ActiveDocument    
MsgBox DocumentoDestino.Shapes(1).Name
```

And also:

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim DocumentoDestino As Object
Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.ActiveDocument    
MsgBox DocumentoDestino.InlineShapes(1).Name
```

But none of these are working.

The error message is "`438: Object doesn't support this property or method`".

Comment: How is it *"not working"*? compilation error? runtime error? not displaying the expected result?

Comment: Thanks, No MsgBox is displayed.

Comment: Is that code block inside some Error handling, such as `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the problem. The error message is "438: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: It seems to me that you are not opening the doc correctly. You should do something like `Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\myPath\myDoc.xlsx")`

Comment: No, it is opening correctly, but the shares are inline shapes, I just checked it. They don't have a name property, so I should promote InlineShapes to Shape type object. How do I do that?

Comment: @NunoNogueira please edit your post and add the rest of the relevant code, it's almost impossible to debug it with the information you have provided

Comment: What type of inline shape is that? a linked image? an Activex control? what do you mean by the name and why do you need it? is it the name of the linked file for example?? And note that if you convert it to shape it will be no longer an inline shape, so that's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: It's an inlineshape copied from Excel to Word. I just figured out that inline shapes and shapes don't have a name property. But they have AlternativeText Property

Comment: Shapes do have a name property. You can try `ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape.Name` but the resulting name is really irrelevant and the shape will no longer be an InlineShape. This is starting to look like XY... It would be useful to explain the end result that you are trying to achieve from this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the WordApp object first.

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim DocumentoDestino As Document

Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.ActiveDocument
```

Comment: Add `MsgBox DocumentoDestino.Shapes.Count` or `MsgBox DocumentoDestino.InlineShapes.Count` to determine if a SAhape or InlineShape exists.

Comment: Ok, I got it! It's inline shape. It doesn't have a name property, so I should promote the  InlineShape to Shape type object. How do I do that?

Comment: Change the TextWrapping property to anything but "Inline with text".